# App not receiving content from Watch

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

Working on a personal project and trying to receive content from an Apple Watch. The data being sent is fine but I get no response from either the phone or the watch.

Inside AppDelegate I have a session started inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and it conforms to `WCSessionDelegate`.

```
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
    var replyValues = [String : Any]()
    switch message["command"] as! String {
    case "logAttempt":
        print("Log attempt")
        replyValues["response"] = "true"
    case "getData":
        print("Get course data")
        replyValues["response"] = "true"
    default:
        break
    }
    replyHandler(replyValues)
```

Inside the WatchKit class it also conforms to `WCSessionDelegate` and has the following to send message to the phone.

```
session.sendMessage(data, replyHandler: { replyHandler in
            print(replyHandler)
            if let response = replyHandler["response"] as? String {
                print("app: Response from app to watch: \(response)")
            } else {
                print("error: Somethings wrong!: \(replyHandler["response"])")
            }
        }) { error in
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

ExtensionDelegate.swift file also conforms to `WCSessionDelegate` and starts a session inside `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. Struggling to get this working.

Thanks!

Edit: Setting up watch inside appDel:

```
fileprivate func setupWatch() {

    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        session = WCSession.default
        session!.delegate = self
        session!.activate()
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you check the configuration of  WCSession ? Check if the delegate object of WCSession is set to the view controller that implements the WCSessionDelegate methods.

Comment: I've tried both on the ViewController and inside AppDelegate, currently trying AppDelegate.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet where you are configuring WCSession?

Comment: Added the method which is called within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: Would I use a viewController method that receives the message data or can I complete this from with AppDelegate? The message data received from the watch should update a local database.

Comment: Joined room....